# GROUP BY + SUM in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran this query.

```
SELECT 
   grupo, 
   solicitante, 
   sum(valuacion) as valuacion, 
   fecha, 
   count(*) as cant, 
   sum(aprobado) as ap, 
   sum(goe) as goe 
FROM 
   presupuestos
WHERE 
   ap=0 AND 
   goe=cant AND 
   grupo>0 AND 
   elim=0 AND 
   sup=0 
GROUP BY grupo 
ORDER BY fecha_aprobacion ASC
```

MySQL returned:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'ap' in 'where clause'
```

Because "ap" is from sum and it is not a row column.

Is there any SQL workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot reference aliases in the `WHERE` clause since the select part of the query is executed last, and the aliases are not yet made. You also can't use aggregate functions in the `WHERE`, you should use `HAVING` instead:

```
SELECT 
   grupo, 
   solicitante, 
   sum(valuacion) as valuacion, 
   fecha, 
   count(*) as cant, 
   sum(aprobado) as ap, 
   sum(goe) as goe 
FROM 
   presupuestos
WHERE 
   grupo>0 AND 
   elim=0 AND 
   aprobado=0 
GROUP BY grupo,solicitante,fecha
HAVING  sum(aprobado)=0 AND sum(goe)= count(*) AND sum(goe)=1
ORDER BY fecha_aprobacion ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to that in your having clause

```
SELECT 
   grupo, 
   solicitante, 
   sum(valuacion) as valuacion, 
   fecha, 
   count(*) as cant, 
   sum(aprobado) as ap, 
   sum(goe) as goe 
FROM 
   presupuestos
WHERE 
   grupo>0 AND 
   elim=0 AND 
   sup=0 AND 
   goe=1 AND 
   aprobado=0 
GROUP BY grupo 
HAVING
   sum(aprobado) = 0 and
   count(*) = sum(goe)
ORDER BY 
   fecha_aprobacion ASC
```

Comment: This won't work - u still have `goe` and `cant` in your `WHERE` clause - they should be moved to the `HAVING` clause as well.

Comment: I would also point out that the `GROUP BY` in this scenario is illogical. Any column that is not contained in an aggregate function **SHOULD BE INCLUDED IN THE** `GROUP BY`. I know MySQL will allow you to do this anyway but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: You might need to remove goe=1 from the where clause into having, but since you have a columns called goe that will work.

Comment: "goe=1 AND" & "aprobado=0" in WHERE clause was my bad, they shouldn't be there. Check the original query in the main post, I edited it. This answer it's right for my needs.