# CodeIgniter Group with SUM

Tags: codeigniter, sum, group

I want to learn CodeIgniter, with an example case like this:

I have a database (tbl_points)

And I have an output like this:

| id | sku | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 10 |
| 2 | 001 | -1 |
| 3 | 002 | 5 |
| 4 | 002 | -2 |
| 5 | 001 | -1 |

I'm having a hard time making groups based on SKUs and then adding up each value at that point. Can you help me to make it like this? Thank you very much.

| id | sku | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 8 |
| 2 | 002 | 3 |

Comment: check e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247059/group-by-sum-in-where-clause and translate the query into a [CI query](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write query for ci3.

```
$this->db->select('sku');
$this->db->select_sum('point');
$this->db->from('tbl_points');
$this->db->group_by('sku');
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$row = $query->result();
          
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i'll try this after Mr Vickel

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved with a simple mysql SUM(), see [Aggregate Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum)

```
select * , sum(`point`) as my_point
from `tbl_points`
group by `sku`
```

in case you really need a new "id", you can extend your query using a [User-Defined Variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) to add on +1 for each new row:

```
set @row_num=0;
select * , sum(`point`) as my_point, @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS new_id
from `tbl_points`
group by `sku`
```

check the corresponding [mysql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eed66/6)

create that query with Codeigniter Query Builder
example for CI3.x:

```
$this->db->select('* , sum(point) as my_point');
$this->db->group_by('sku');
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_points');
```

and with the User-Defined Variable you need 2 queries, something like:

```
$sql="set @row_num:=0";
$this->db->query($sql);

$sql="select * , sum(`point`) as my_point, @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS new_id
from `tbl_points`
group by `sku`
";

$query=$this->db->query($sql);
```

to quickly output the result, you could write this line:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($query->result());
```

anyway recommendable to check [How to Generate CI Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum it first, then group by this fields :-

```
$sql = "select id,sku, sum(`point`) as my_point from `tbl_points`
group by `sku`";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

to output the result:-

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query->result());
```

**Your Output result :-**

```
id  sku my_point
1   001 8
3   002 3
```